# Android openFileInput() for cache?

Tags: android, storage

If I understand Android [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) correctly, at the very least Internal and External Storage have 2 directories:

```
Internal Storage Files = getFilesDir()
Internal Storage Cache = getCacheDir()
External Storage Files = getExternalFilesDir()
External Storage Cache = getExternalCacheDir()
```

`FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` of both directories of External Storage can be created using constructor. For example:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

In Internal Storage, however, you may only use `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` to create `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream`. For example:

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName);
FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And since `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()` create `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` from Internal Storage Files `getFilesDir()`, I assume the constructor of `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` are the only method that can be used for Internal Storage Cache `getCacheDir()`. Can someone with greater knowledge verify that information above is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Internal Storage, however, you may only use openFileInput() and openFileOutput() to create FileInputStream or FileOutputStream.

No, you can use `getFilesDir()` and `getCacheDir()` to create locations on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), such as `new File(getCacheDir(), fileName)`.

> I assume the constructor of FileInputStream and FileOutputStream are the only method that can be used for Internal Storage Cache getCacheDir().

There is no `openFileInput()` direct equivalent for `getCacheDir()`, if that is what you mean.

Comment: if so, is there a workaround to achieve `openFileInput()` for `getCacheDir()`?

Comment: @HendraAnggrian: Use `new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), fileName))`.

Comment: fantastic. one more concern: can we use the same method for `getFilesDir()`? Something like `new FileInputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), fileName))`. How is that different from `openFileInput()`?

Comment: @HendraAnggrian: "How is that different from openFileInput()?" -- it is no different, AFAIK.